# Openpyxl formulas conflict

Tags: python, excel, formula, openpyxl

I am writing this code to assign a formula to an specific cell depending on the row. But the problem is that when I try to open the Excel file it throws me an error and delete the formula I wrote.

```
for z in range(4, 54):
     wss.cell(coordinate="J"+str(z), value="=I"+str(z)+"*C"+str(z))
     formula = "=SI(ESBLANCO(H"+str(z)+");0;BUSCARV(H"+str(z)+ ";Lista_precios!A3:B"+str(self.ultimaFila+1)+";2;FALSO))"
     wss.cell(coordinate="I"+str(z), value=formula)
```

I am writing the Excel formulas in Spanish because my Excel is in Spanish.
The first formula that is simply =I4*C4 works fine.
I have printed the variable formula and it is in accordance with Excel but has conflict with Openpyxl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must write the formula in English and use a comma to separate variables because this is how they are stored in the OOXML file format.

Comment: Thank you. It works. 
I wrote the formula in Python in English and when I open de Excel file it is in Spanish.